# Exit if Windows version is less than 7

Tags: c#, .net, string-comparison

How can I do it? I followed [this](https://andrewensley.com/2009/06/c-detect-windows-os-part-1/) tutorial, so I have this method:

```
if (getOSInfo() >= "7")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your Microsoft Windows version isn't supported.\n\nPlease use Windows 7 or above to be able to use this program.");
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

It gives an error:

> Cannot apply operator >= to operands of type string and string

Comment: method `getOSInfo()` I have posted already (as a link to the source) https://andrewensley.com/2009/06/c-detect-windows-os-part-1/

and the error is `Cannot apply operator >= to operands of type string and string`

Comment: What is so difficult to understand with the rather clear error message "_Cannot apply operator >= to operands of type string and string_"? You cannot use relational operators such as <, >, <= and >= with strings. Use string.Compare(...).

Comment: I can't post all code into the question, because my question content becomes mostly code and I can't save it.

Comment: The method you link to returns names like "Vista" , "7" and "2000". That is not compatible with `>=` or `String.Compare()`. In .Net, use Environment.OsVersion and find your cutoff point. And if it's not NT, is't before "7".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the method `getOSInfo` return string data-type and it included "**98**" , "**ME**" ,  "**XP**" and you can't compare it with `>=` operator, you can change it to below code:

```
if(Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 1)
{
    // whatever you want to do...
}
```

And as **@nelek** mentioned, this is a comprehensive article about operation system versions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/operating-system-version

Comment: And application will be quit if Windows version is any version but 7... Imagine some application support Win7, but not WinXP and Win8, 10... Little strange, isn't?

Comment: @nelek you right, I corrected my answer

Comment: Again me ;) ... You have to change value for `Version.Minor > 1` to `>0`, because `Minor=1` is Win7... User application will support Win7 also.. You can see here list of Win versions :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/operating-system-version

Comment: @ I was too distracted these days :(

Comment: @nelek I read that page, and that was so helpful, thank you.

Comment: Note how your snippet misbehaves when they release version 7.0  Otherwise a very good demonstration why Microsoft has to lie about version numbers :)